# DropDown list onchange event and AJAX in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

I have a code block in my MVC view as follows:

```
<%using (Ajax.BeginForm("MyAction", new { action = "MyAction", controller = "Home", id = ViewData["selected"].ToString() }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Div1" }))
     { %>
          <%=Html.DropDownList("ddl", ViewData["MyList"] as SelectList, new { onchange = "this.form.submit()" })%>
                 <%} %>
```

I want to set the value of ViewData["selected"] so that i can send it to the desired action.
Can anyone please suggest how can i do this?

thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of using a form, why not use a jQuery onChange event on your drop down?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ddl").change(function() {
        var strSelected = "";
        $("#ddl option:selected").each(function() {
            strSelected += $(this)[0].value;
        });
        var url = "/Home/MyAction/" + strSelected;

        $.post(url, function(data) {
            // do something if necessary
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer on how to do it with a form and ASP.MVC. http://stackoverflow.com/q/10566923/706363

Comment: [some](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4100182/2218697) use `$.ajax({ ` and you are using `$.post`, so what is the difference which is best for ajax Get and Post ?

Answer (score 2):

ViewData is not the place to pass data back to the server side.  Values of html input controls within form tag are conveniently available in action method. You can get these values either from various types of action method arguments (model, formcollection etc).

Here is a link to [free asp.net mvc ebook tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/03/10/free-asp-net-mvc-ebook-tutorial.aspx).  Is a good resource for asp.net mvc.

Comment: @Elisabeth This is super old, but I couldn't help but notice your comment: When Ricky posted this, MVC 2.0 had only been released for about 2 months, so it was a legitimate link at the time :-)

Answer (score 0):

Found solution at this post [it is just small chnge](http://localwire.pl/ajax-beginform-on-dropdownlist-change/)

Yes, that’s right – only change is replacing:

onchange = “this.form.submit();”

with:

onchange = “$(this.form).submit();”