# Using ajax to update fields in a view based off of dropdown onchange with a method in the DAL

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view that has a dropdown that is generated by a linq statement when the view is populated.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OrderID, "Order ID")
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OrderID, Model.Orders, "Select Order ID", 
        new { @id = "orderDropdown" })
   </div>
</div>
```

I have 2 other fields in the view that need to be updated with the data retrieved from the database.

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Final Weight")
        <div id="finalWeight">
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FinalWeight)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Initial Weight")
        <div id="initialWeight">
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.InitialWeight)
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the ajax that I got from the link below:

```
<script>
$("#orderDropdown").change(function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        url:"???" + $(this).val(),/* not sure what to use*/
        data: { id: $(this).val()},
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            $("#divinitialWeight").html(data);
        }

    });
});
```

Here is the controller code

```
 [HttpGet]
    [OpenAction]
    public async Task<float> GetInitialWeight(int sid)
    {
       var initialWeight = await Manager.FindInitialFilterWeightBySID(sid);

        return  initialWeight.MeanWeight;
    }
```

The method is in a Data Access Layer that is only referenced in the main project. The way I would call it in the controller would be like below and pass it the orderId :

```
Entities.Manager.FindInitialWeight(orderId);
Entities.Manager.FindFinalWeight(orderId);
```

I came across [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078553/ajax-call-on-onchange-event-in-mvc) and it's close to what I need but the only issue is the `url:` because the data retrieval method is not in my controller...it is in the data access layer that is only a reference. Also the orderId is being passed as a parameter.

How can I call that method from ajax and pass it the orderId from the `url:` of the ajax call?

Comment: Can you share your controller code?

Comment: Which controller exactly? The one that populates the view or the one in the DAL that queries the database?

Comment: @FelixCen I added the controller code and the javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can call the controller method from JQuery like this
if the JQuery code is within the razor view

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetInitialWeight")',
data: { sid: $(this).val()},
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually had to create a `GET` method in my controller that contacted the DAL with the passed parameter from the javascript

```
[HttpGet]
    [OpenAction]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetInitialWeight(int sid)
    {
       var initialWeight = await Manager.FindInitialFilterWeightBySID(sid);

        return Json(new { initialWeight.MeanWeight }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Then change the javascript as such

```
<script>
$("#sidDropdown").change(function (event) {

    var url = "/Controller/GetInitialWeight/";
    var data = { sid: $(this).val() };
    var dataType = "json";
    $.get(
        url,
        data,
    function (response) {
        $("div#initialWeight").text(response.MeanWeight)
        console.log(response.MeanWeight);
    }, dataType);

});
```