# Using Jquery to collect data, use data to get a Partial View from the controller, and append the passed information to the end of a page

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery, partial-views

I am attempting to append a partial view to the end of my 'currently displayed page' when a selection from a dropdown menu is chosen.

This is the dropdown from my view:

```
<div>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.DropDownInfo, Model.Info, "DefaultSelection")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Courses)
</div>
```

I am in most need here in my Jquery.  What do I need to do to append the PartialView that is returned by my controller (pasted below)?  My current Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#DropDownInfo").change(function() {
        var strSelected = "";
        $("#DropDownInfo option:selected").each(function() {
            strSelected += $(this)[0].value;
        });
        var url = "/Controller/PreFillMethod/?MethodString=" + strSelected;

        $.post(url, function(data) {
            //*****
            // Assuming everything else is correct,
            // what do I do here to have my partial view returned 
            // at the end of the currently displayed page?
            //*****
        });
    });
});
```

This is the part of my controller that replies with a PartialView (I want the string from the dropdown selection to be passed into this controller to ultimately be used to fill in a field in the PartialView's form) :

```
public PartialViewResult PreFillCourse(string selectedFromDropDown)
{
    ViewBag.selectedString = selectedFromDropDown;
    MyViewModel preFill = new MyViewModel
    {
        Title = selectedFromDropDown, // I am using this to pre-fill a field in a form
    };
    return PartialView("_PartialViewForm", preFill);
}
```

The Partial View (in the case that it matters):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>CourseTemplates</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

I am open to suggestions if I am approaching the situation entirely incorrectly.

My goal is to have a user select a 'template' from the drop-down menu and have that template's data autopopulate into a form below the drop-down.

My Jquery is very rough - I am using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2238870/1026898) as a guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have a div in your view

```
<div id ="divToAppend">
</div>
```

then append the partial view to your div

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#DropDownInfo").change(function() {
        var strSelected = "";
        $("#DropDownInfo option:selected").each(function() {
            strSelected += $(this)[0].value;
        });
        var url = "/Controller/PreFillMethod/?MethodString=" + strSelected;

        $.post(url, function(data) {
             $('#divToAppend').html(data);

            //*****
            // Assuming everything else is correct,
            // what do I do here to have my partial view returned 
            // at the end of the currently displayed page?
            //*****


          });
    });
});
```

Comment: Sounds correct, however - if I make those changes, selecting an option from the drop-down still does nothing. I must be missing something else.

Comment: are you sure you are getting any response from the controller, you can check this by checking "data" variable is null or not

Comment: Must not have refreshed properly, it works - thank you sincerely.

Comment: Actually, what changed was I was using Chrome instead of IE - is there any reason why this wouldn't work in IE 9?  (works in chrome)

Comment: only reason I can figure is Javascript is not enabled in IE, pls check it